# Scrape Links/Href CSS

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, css-selectors

The following code scrapes names, company and location of users on LinkedIn.

I want the link/Href per user [image: picture]

The code requires log in credentials for LinkedIn, you can use fake account if skeptical.

Or you can just look at the code/screenshot, anything helps.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
productlinks=[]
test1=[]

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fsearch%2Fresults%2Fpeople%2F%3FcurrentCompany%3D%255B%25221252860%2522%255D%26geoUrn%3D%255B%2522103644278%2522%255D%26keywords%3Dsales%26origin%3DFACETED_SEARCH%26page%3D2&fromSignIn=true&trk=cold_join_sign_in"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('jazizi@lifesciencedynamics.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')

password.send_keys('Theboss3!')
password.submit()

element1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name actor-name")
title=[t.text for t in element1]
print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better using BeautifulSoup, but if you post more code about the page source it will be easyer to help you

with bs4 you can get all html structure of an element and then maybe with regex get the href attribute

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the worst thing you can do in web scrape is get element by class. Because in web development, we normally use class for almost any style decorating. Try xpath or id instead.
2. The second thing I noticed in your code is: you find element by class and the parameter inside is multi class name `name actor-name`. I haven't read the code nor try running it so I don't understand how it works at this moment. But you should be aware of it, because in web development, `class="name actor-name"` and `class="actor-name name"` are almost the same *(I did say almost, this is the second time I am mentioning it)*, but in web scraping it will be entirely different.